# LIMIT with SELECT COUNT query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm wanting to limit an INSERT with a number of rows of another table like this:

```
INSERT INTO pacte (alianca_en_pacte, tipus)
SELECT id_alianca_en_pacte1 ,tipus_pacte1
FROM c_alianca
LIMIT 0, SELECT COUNT(tipus_pacte1) FROM c_alianca WHERE tipus_pacte1 IS NOT NULL
```

The following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(tipus_pacte1) FROM c_alianca WHERE tipus_pacte1 IS NOT NULL
```

returns a **4**

When running the script, the following error apears:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT * FROM c_alianca' at line 4

Comment: you can't use subquery on limit but also, you don't need it. make your limitation on your query. Check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just query your criteria and insert those like this?

```
INSERT INTO pacte (alianca_en_pacte, tipus)
SELECT id_alianca_en_pacte1 ,tipus_pacte1
FROM c_alianca
WHERE tipus_pacte1 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Duh.  I was thinking too literally!  +1

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I think I was racking my brain when it was so simple..

Answer (score 4):

MySQL currently doesn't support having a subquery as an argument to `LIMIT`.  You will need to use user variables across two queries:

```
SET @limit = (
    SELECT COUNT(tipus_pacte1) FROM c_alianca WHERE tipus_pacte1 IS NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO pacte (alianca_en_pacte, tipus)
    SELECT id_alianca_en_pacte1 ,tipus_pacte1
    FROM c_alianca
    LIMIT 0, @limit;
```

But [as suggested by Nesim Razon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10279099/623041), in your example one can avoid using `LIMIT` entirely:

```
INSERT INTO pacte (alianca_en_pacte, tipus)
    SELECT id_alianca_en_pacte1 ,tipus_pacte1
    FROM c_alianca
    WHERE tipus_pacte1 IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're after

```
INSERT INTO pacte (alianca_en_pacte, tipus)
SELECT id_alianca_en_pacte1, tipus_pacte1, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(tipus_pacte1) FROM c_alianca WHERE tipus_pacte1 IS NOT NULL ) AS tipus 
FROM c_alianca LIMIT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
below is the code for Limitation on ID....It is the example for you
Declare @Counter int 
Set @Counter=(SELECT Count(Student_ID) as 'StudentCount' FROM CourseSemOne 
where Student_ID=1 Having Count(Student_ID) < 6 and Count(Student_ID) > 0)
if(@Counter <6)
print'Sorry! You cannot add more than five subject data for a single student'
else
print'Insert Code';
```